# Python gRPC: Cannot import <generated module> from proto

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, grpc

I have a gRPC service, for which python grpc compiler generated two files in the `proto` directory:

- `service_pb2.py`
- `service_pb2_grpc.py`

In the `service_pb2_grpc.py` there is an import `from proto import service_pb2 as proto_dot__service__pb2`. This import fails because in my virtualenv I have another package called `proto` which seems to be a dependency of google cloud logging library. So import is attempted from site package, not from the proto directory. I don't want to run some script after compiler does its job, to rename this generated proto directory. Is there a way to tell the grpc compiler which name to use for proto containing folder?

Comment: Did you try relative imports instead of absolute? This is not the best way to solve it tho. The best way would be renaming your `proto` folder

Comment: Sure, it would be better to rename the folder. But, I will also have to rename the proto files, which scream at me "DO NOT EDIT". Thus I don't like this approach of manual renaming.

Comment: Then wrap it with one more package. For it to be `package.proto.service_pb2`

Comment: The import inside generated files will still be `from proto import ...`, even if `proto` directory will be inside another package, right?